# Intellij icon with two red horizontal lines

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA for a Scala project. Many of my files have icons with two red horizontal lines on them, like so:

- [class icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5obN.png)
- [library? icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJGc3.png)

I don't know what these mean. I've looked at the Intellij Symbols reference (would link to it but I don't have enough rep) but didn't see these icons listed. I also tried mousing over each icon to see if there were any tooltips, but I didn't get anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ uses glyphs to give you a visual clue to the language of a file (below you see a python one and a Scala one). The two lines are  reminiscent of the Scala logo, (which actually has 3 strips, see for example https://www.scala-lang.org)

[image])

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to Scala. :)

Comment: would be nice to have reference to all scala related intellij icons

Comment: I have another question: some scala code shows a brownish circle, while some shows icon with 3 red horizontal lines, what is the difference?